# Javascript Runtime error: $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have added script in my **Default.aspx** page. I am getting following error.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$` is defined by jQuery, which you probably haven't referenced. A simple way to get it is to add one of the CDN urls to your template HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so I need to remove $ ? I have added path of my script but not works

Comment: @Ajay: No. `$` is missing. That's what `'$' is undefined` means. You need to include jQuery, which defines `$` for you, in order to make your code work.

Comment: @Ajay: Just to be clear, the code you've pasted into your HTML relies on jQuery. The `$` is a short-hand reference to the jQuery object. Removing the `$`s isn't an option. The code won't work at all if you don't include jQuery.

Comment: I added the JQUERY url in both my MasterPage.master and Default.aspx and I am still receiving the error. Any idea how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: @SiKni8: Ask a new question.

Comment: I have a same problem , but its not resolve the  Your Solution

Answer (score 4):

You need to include jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    **<script src="jquery.js"></script>**
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In that case you haven't included it, or in the right location. It needs to be included before you make any calls to $

Comment: I have a same problem , but its not resolve the Your Solution

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but did have a correct reference to jQuery.

I solved it by referencing jQuery *before* any other scripts. In your case, it would look like this:

```
<script src= "scripts/jquery-ui.js" />
<script src= "scripts/JavaScript_scroll.js" />
```

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Oh, yes. I realized my jQuery was inside     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") so I moved it up before the html and that error disappeared. It turns out I had a control called "WebGrid" that was calling an ajax function in the middle of my HTML so it needed the jquery before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the Same Problem as that $ is Unidentified, After a long struggle, I come to know that there is some thing HTML coder error in Master Page, `So it worked fine when i include the Jquery files directly in Content page`[image]

Comment: I have a same problem , but its not resolve the Your Solution

Answer (score 0):

(For others who may face the same problem as OP's)
I had the same problem, but the reason was that I was trying to load my `jQuery` script before loading the `jQuery` library itself. In other words, make sure that you first add this line:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"></script>
```

before adding

```
<script src="Scripts/JavaSript_scroll.js"></script>
```