# JQuery doesn't work in javascript when partial is returned from controller after post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, http-post, http-get

I'm in visual studio making an asp.net project. I've got two controller functions [HttpGet] AccountCreate and [HttpPost] AccountCreate.
The Get returns a PartialView with model AccountCreatePageModel. Everything works here, my javascript and jquery are solid. When I submit the form I check to make sure an input is unique, if it's not I send the partial view back the same way as with the Get. But when it loads and tries to run the javascript, every place that uses $ for jquery breaks, so I guess it doesn't know what jquery is anymore. How can this be? It was all done the same way as the Get.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult AccountCreate(Guid functionId, long? parentId)
    {
        AccountCreatePageModel model = new AccountCreatePageModel
        {
            Function = DataFactory.SystemAccess.GetFunction(functionId),
            ParentId = parentId
        };

        if (parentId != default(long?))
        {
            model.Account = DataFactory.PartyAccess.GetAccount((long)parentId);
            model.Organization = DataFactory.PartyAccess.GetOrganizationByAccountId(model.Account.Id);
            model.Person = DataFactory.PartyAccess.InitializePerson();
            model.Account.Id = (long)parentId;                
        }
        else
        {
            model.Account = DataFactory.PartyAccess.InitializeAccount();
            model.Organization = DataFactory.PartyAccess.InitializeOrganization();
            model.Person = DataFactory.PartyAccess.InitializePerson();
            model.Address = DataFactory.PartyAccess.InitializeAddress();
        }

        model.PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumberModel();

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AccountCreate(AccountCreatePageModel model)
    {

        long id = 0;
        long phoneNumberParentId = 0;
        long accountId = 0;

        if (model.Account.Id > 0)
        {
            accountId = model.Account.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            accountId = DataFactory.PartyAccess.UpsertAccount(model.Account, true).Id;
            model.Function = DataFactory.SystemAccess.GetFunction(model.Function.Id);
            if (accountId == -1)     //Account.AccountId already exists, send message back to user
            {
                return PartialView(model); //this returns my partial back
            }
        }
```

Here is razor HTML

```
@using Application.Web.Extensions
@model Application.Web.Models.AccountCreatePageModel

@if ((Model.Organization.Id == 0) && (Model.Person.Id == 0))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#Organization_Name').rules('remove');
            $('#Person_LastName').rules('remove');
            $('#btnSave').click( function (e) {

                if (($('#Organization_Name').val() == "" &&         $('#Person_LastName').val() === "") || ($('#Person_FirstName').val() !== "" && $('#Person_LastName').val() === "")) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("OrgLastNameError").innerHTML =      "Organization Name or Last Name must be provided";
                }
                if ($('#Person_FirstName').val() !== "" &&   $('#Person_LastName').val() === "") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("OrgLastNameError").innerHTML =   "Last Name must be provided";
                    $('#Person_LastName').focus();
                }

                //if($('#'))

            });
        });
    </script>
}
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Function.Id)
<div class="row">
    <div id="OrgLastNameError" class="text-danger"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @Html.PartialFor(model => Model.Account, "_AccountEdit", new    ViewDataDictionary { { "Readonly", (Model.Account.Id > 0) } })
</div>
<div class="row">@Html.PartialFor(model => Model.Organization,   "_OrganizationEdit", new ViewDataDictionary { { "Readonly",   (Model.Organization.Id > 0) } })</div>

<div class="row">@Html.PartialFor(model => Model.Person, "_PersonEdit")  </div>
```

Comment: Please add code - front end code

Comment: There's the controller code and the immediate html code used. The javascript at the top breaks when it encounters the first '$' symbol and says something about how it doesn't know what it is

Comment: What exactly does not work when you say code breaks when encounter first $

Comment: I get this: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: If I hit continue, every spot that uses jquery or '$' it runs a javascript error

Comment: How are you adding jQuery to your page?

Comment: It's in my _Layout. When I return the partial from the HttpGet it puts the partial inside the main _Layout that is used every time. I don't see why the HttpPost wouldn't put the partial inside _Layout as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to join the comment discussion so I'll post here. There are a lot of good answers here:

[Javascript Runtime error: $ is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637870/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined)

I would also like to say that you are not fully leveraging the model. I would suggest that handling validation that happens in your controller within the model itself. In your controller, you can add:

```
        if (accountId == -1)    
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account id already exists.")
            return PartialView(model); //this returns my partial back
        }
```

And you can then display that in the view with:

```
Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Also, I see that you are validating fields locally, this can be problematic for a number of reasons. MVC also gives us the option to add validation within the model. If you add onto your model property:

```
[Required]
public string MyModelProperty{get; set;}
```

The model will throw an error when a user tries to submit the form without any data in that field.

Comment: The issue appears to be it's not going through my _Layout which is where it grabs all of my jquery and special scripts and css styling. _Layout is also where I grab my Navigation Bar for every screen. When I return the partial from my Post method, it isn't getting any of that. It returns JUST the partial, so it doesn't have any references to styling or jquery or anything. If I hit okay through all of the javascript errors I am given just the html of my partial. None of my other stuff like the navigation bar which is grabbed from my _Layout normally

Comment: Are you treating your Layout as a main view? It's named like a partialView. Try returning the specific partial that you actually want, I'm not sure what PartialView() with no argument for view name returns by default.

Comment: return PartialView("_YourPartialName", model);