# Why my custom js in bundle doesn't show up in custom view MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to exract some js file and call it only in one view, separetely from my bundles which is called from _LandingLayout.cshtml template page.

**In my BundleConfig.cs** I have

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/app/index").Include(
          "~/Scripts/App/home.js",
          "~/Scripts/App/location.js"
         ));
```

**and my view** like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LandingLayout.cshtml";
 }

 <!-- Main Content -->
  ...some html markup
 <!-- End of Main Content -->
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/app/index")
```

every css and js file from _LandingLayout.cshtml is shows correctly, if I put "~/scripts/app/index" into _LandingLayout.cshtml, it shows correctly.

But if I want to render it separately from my _LandingLayout.cshtml it enters into js file home.js and yellows whole the file like a debugger (I didn't put any debugger into my home.js) and when I enter F10, I get an error:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I have searched for this error and [I find this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637870/javascript-runtime-error-is-undefined)
But, I have referenced jQuery lib.

Only that cross my mind, that maybe engine renders first my line of code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/app/index")
```

and later on renders all bundles from _LandingLayout.cshtml page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add you new section in `_LandingLayout.cshtml` view after all js files referenced inside it.
for example we will add section named `"ExtraJs"` after jquery reference as following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("ExtraJs", false)
```

then inside your view you can reference this section as following

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LandingLayout.cshtml";
 }

 <!-- Main Content -->
  ...some html markup
 <!-- End of Main Content -->

@section ExtraJs
{
  @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/app/index")
}
```